# How to change default title of the UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbar

I want to use standard tab bar item with custom title. I change title after TabBarItem creating directly *self.tabBarItem.title = @"Liked"*. For example "Favorites" - UITabBarSystemItemFavorites:

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Liked", @"Liked");
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:0];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Liked";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Can I do this? If yes, where I made mistake?

**UPD:** Changing tab bar item *title* in the *viewDidLoad()* works on iOS4 but doesn't work on iOS5. Does exist another approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should do that in the `viewDidLoad` and not in the init.

Comment: sorry, but this approach works for me only on iOS 4.3, but for iOS 5 it doesn't work :-( Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that something is override your title. Check the lifeCycle of  your ViewController in order to track down where this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As per Swift5.1 and Xcode the title and image of the system tab bar items cannot be changed. They are defined as enum in obj c as follow. This is the list:

```swift
typedef enum UITabBarSystemItem : NSInteger {
case more, favorites, featured, topRated, recents, contacts, history, bookmarks, search, downloads ,mostRecent, mostViewed
} UITabBarSystemItem;
```

This has a reason. Some icons are immediately recognisable across the whole iOS ecosystem and mean the same thing to everyone, therefore it is not possible to use them differently. 
In this way Apple creates a better user experience. 
You cannot use the Apple icon and use a different title. You could use a custom icon and custom title instead or in the Storyboards select an SF Symbol like this:

[image]